# SVG path animation not as expected

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

The moon needs to move in that path same as the one with id of `trajectory` around the planet. But it is moving randomly (as if it's celebrating 4/20).

Please find the attached code.

```css
.moon {
  offset-path: path('m159.39 54.867a71.83 20.37 0 0 1-71.83 20.37 71.83 20.37 0 0 1-71.83-20.37 71.83 20.37 0 0 1 71.83-20.37 71.83 20.37 0 0 1 71.83 20.37z');
  animation: revolve 10s 1s infinite ease-in-out forwards;
}

@keyframes revolve {
  from {
    offset-distance: 0%;
  }

  to {
    offset-distance: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="169.31" height="115.66" viewBox="0 0 169.31 115.66">
  <circle cx="87.56" cy="54.867" r="45.855" fill="#ff4141" />
  <circle class="moon" cx="18.051" cy="54.867" r="8.092" fill="#ff9900" />
  <path
        id="trajectory"
        d="m18.051 54.867c1.9043-12.055 45.047-20.455 69.073-20.601 25.048-0.15208 64.422 2.9195 72.266 20.601-6.7091 16.516-45.54 20.472-69.791 20.552-24.814 0.082685-67.739-4.5793-71.548-20.552z"
        fill="none" stroke-width=".5px" stroke="#000000" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`offset-path` is not yet supported enough by browsers [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=offset-path)

To realize the moon moving along a trajectory, consider using [animateMotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)

```html
<svg width="169.31" height="115.66" viewBox="0 0 169.31 115.66">
  <circle cx="87.56" cy="54.867" r="45.855" fill="#ff4141" />
  <circle class="moon" cx="0" cy="0" r="8.092" fill="#ff9900" >
    <animateMotion begin="0s"
   dur="12s" repeatCount="3"  fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" >>
  <mpath xlink:href="#trajectory" />
 </animateMotion>
  </circle>
  <path
        id="trajectory"
        d="m18.051 54.867c1.9043-12.055 45.047-20.455 69.073-20.601 25.048-0.15208 64.422 2.9195 72.266 20.601-6.7091 16.516-45.54 20.472-69.791 20.552-24.814 0.082685-67.739-4.5793-71.548-20.552z"
        fill="none" stroke-width=".5px" stroke="#000000" />
  
</svg>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @thewebjackal I changed the center of the moon so that it falls on the path of movement Try changing these parameters and you will see that the moon will rotate next to the path

Comment: Yes, actually I observed that thing. The moon went out of viewBox. I then realized the center of the moon has been changed. Thanks again! Edit: I also removed the fill="freeze" and it went to 0,0. HAha!